# 'waiting for network connection' error on boot

Tags: boot, configuration, networking

When I start my system, all the process is perfectly normal, until this message appears: 'waiting for network configuration' after that one there comes 'waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration' and finally, like after 3 minutes of waiting, there comes 'booting system without full network configuration'.

Normally, at home I'm connected through a normal wired internet connection, but when I need to take my laptop to any other place without a wired internet connection like work or the university, the above mentioned messages appear and well... I really get a bit pissed off.

Is there any possibility to make my system stop trying to configure the network at boot when I have absolutely no network to configure?

I don't really mind modifying my system settings every time I come home or go to work so, maybe if there is a solution like 'well this is going to stop the booting network configuration, but when you need to use a wired network you will have to reconfigure it' it's going to be perfect.

Comment: I agree, this is a really dumb change for laptops.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report with some proposals how to overcome the issue.

[bug 811441](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/811441)

good luck